# Como Liberar un Pdf Creado con Itextsharp y Filestream c#

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Al momento de crear mi Pdf me lo abre y no me da ningún error, pero si lo quiero volver abrir teniendo anteriormente abierto el primero me da este error

> 'El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo 'C:\Sistema_De_Cotizaciones_Vista_Previa\Vista_Previa.pdf' porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso.'

Lo que busco es poder abrir el mismo archivo aunque este este abierto, quiero liberar el archivo cuando se termina de crear para que al momento de volverlo a crear este disponible.

```
string filename = @"C:\Sistema_De_Cotizaciones_Vista_Previa\Vista_Previa.pdf";
                      
Document Documento_Pdf_Marsys = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 36, 36, 36, 85);

using (PdfWriter pdfWrite = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Documento_Pdf_Marsys,new FileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create)))
{
    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle Page = Documento_Pdf_Marsys.PageSize;
    Documento_Pdf_Marsys.Open();

    //cuerpo del pdf//
    //cuerpo del pdf//
    //cuerpo del pdf//
    //cuerpo del pdf//

    Documento_Pdf_Marsys.Dispose();
    Documento_Pdf_Marsys.Close(); // SE CIERRA EL DOCUMENTO
    Documento_Pdf_Marsys.CloseDocument();
    pdfWrite.Close();
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename);
```

Comment: agrega todo el codigo del metodo asi se podra ver si falta alguna instruccion

Comment: Ya agrege el codigo